# How to save the terminal output in columns?

Tags: python, selenium

How can I save terminal output to a single column in pandas?

```
btn = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, 
"/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/header[1]/div[2]/div[2]")
btn.get_attribute("title")
sleep(2)
print(btn.text)
```

I need to use .text in btn, to get the desired result.

I'm using selenium to extract the information

terminal exit

[image]

The element that separates the information is the comma.

[image]

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(btn.text.split(', '), columns=['title'])`

Comment: Can you share the html of that element?